# Aiogram: How do you keep the ability to handle the Inline button in a past message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

There is a bot where a user can find out information about a player by nickname. The user enters the nickname of the player, for example Player1, gets information about the player with Inline button, let's say "Update information". Then the user enters the nickname of another player, Player2, the information about him with the same button is displayed.

How can I make it so that the user can click on the "Update information" button in the message about Player1 and the information about Player1 will be updated?

Tried to do it with a dictionary, but it didn't work.